# Streaming a zip file from iOS app to web browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My app runs an HTTP server which can be connected to a desktop web browser on the same Wifi network.  This currently handles individual requests for images etc.

I would like to find a way to transfer multiple images & files over to the browser in one go.  The sizes would be too large to construct in iPhone memory before sending over.

I've considered creating a .zip file and streaming files into it one at a time, but unsure how I could go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a ZIP file is fairly straightforward. I've only done it myself the other way around (decompression a ZIP file I've downloaded), but the majority of available libraries support both compression and decompression.

You can either use one of the lower-level C libraries, or one of several Objective-C wrappers that various people have written.

My personal wrapper of choice is ZipKit: https://bitbucket.org/kolpanic/zipkit/wiki/Home

It is fairly straightforward to use, so it may be a good first port of call for you.

Comment: Since I can't answer my own questions for 8 hours(!):I have had some success using Objective-Zip in the end (http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/).  This allowed me to create a large temporary zip file on the iPhone by adding single files to the archive.

The HTTP server I'm using works with a file handle, to which I sent archive using dataWithContentsOfMappedFile.


[fileHandle writeData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfMappedFile:tempArchiveFilename]];